# Getting error executable file not found in $PATH when trying verbose run docker container or when docker exec

Tags: docker, vuejs2, dockerfile

I am trying to containerize my vue-js app: and below is my docker file:

```
FROM node:9.11.1-alpine

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

when I try to run docker with verbose flag `-v` I get this error:

```
$ docker run -it vue-js-app -v
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"-v\": executable file not found in $PATH".
```

and without `-v` flag I get the below:

```
$ docker run -it vue-js-app
Starting up http-server, serving dist
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://172.17.0.3:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

and then if I try to enter the container:

```
$ docker exec -it 0778c0e3ae05  bash
oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

I get same error , but navigating to ip address with port i get page not found

Comment: Bash not found is explainable, because alpine knows /bin/sh. But what I cannot explain is where you try to enter the container and in which way. So I think your question is incomplete describing the circumstances.

Comment: I see I used ash instead of bash and I am able to ssh container..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format of the `docker container run` command is:

```
Usage:  docker container run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

So, when you execute `docker run -it vue-js-app -v`, the `-v` is being passed to the container as the command, replacing the command specified in the Dockerfile (`CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]`). This results in the message “executable file not found in $PATH” because there is not a command named `-v` in the container.

If you are trying to pass `-v` to `http-server`, you have to repeat the existing command in the Dockerfile.

```
docker container run -it vue-js-app http-server dist -v
```

This will run `http-server dist -v` in the container.

As for executing a shell in the container, bash is not found in $PATH because bash is not installed in the image. `node:9.11.1-alpine` is based on Alpine Linux, which uses `ash` as the default shell. So, you should use ash to execute a shell process in your running container.

```
docker container exec -it 0778c0e3ae05 ash
```

Comment: still gives me same error:`$ docker container run -it vue-js-app http-server dist -v
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"http-server\": executable file not found in $PATH".`

Comment: Have you changed the Dockerfile/Docker image since you originally posted the question? Repeating the command specified in a Dockerfile in `docker container run` should produce exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You write: "get same error , but navigating to ip address with port i get page not found".

This is because you do not map the port. You EXPOSE it, bu you should also map it. Find information in docker docs in the reference for the run command under header:
 EXPOSE (incoming ports): 
https://docs.docker.com/v1.13/engine/reference/run/

> -P         : Publish all exposed ports to the host interfaces.
>   -p=[]      : Publish a container᾿s port or a range of ports to the host
>                  format: ip:hostPort:containerPort | ip::containerPort | hostPort:containerPort | containerPort
>                  Both hostPort and containerPort can be specified as a
>                  range of ports. When specifying ranges for both, the
>                  number of container ports in the range must match the
>                  number of host ports in the range, for example: -p 1234-1236:1234-1236/tcp
>   When specifying a range for hostPort only, the
>                  containerPort must not be a range.  In this case the
>                  container port is published somewhere within the
>                  specified hostPort range. (e.g., `-p 1234-1236:1234/tcp`) (use 'docker port' to see the actual mapping)

Comment: you are right , my bad even after I have used it in the past I forgot to publish: so i got it working like this: `docker container run -it -p 8080:8080 vue-js-app http-server dist -v`
thanks